# Is there a way to skip few commands in a for loop by checking the condition before?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I want to ask if there is a way to skip few commands in a for loop by checking the condition before.

Here is an example to you understand my question.

---

I want to add `1` to `a` and append `a` to a list `a_list` for `n_iter` times.
But, appending `a` should be done only if `flag` is `True`.

I think the code can be wrriten in two ways.

---

**CODE 1**

```
a = 0
a_list = []
n_iter = 10
flag = False
for _ in range(n_iter):
    a += 1
    if flag:
        a_list.append(a)
```

---

**CODE 2**

```
a = 0
a_list = []
n_iter = 10
flag = False
if flag:
    for _ in range(n_iter):
        a += 1
        a_list.append(a)
else:
    for _ in range(n_iter):
        a += 1
```

---

The **CODE 1** has fewer lines, but it requires to check the condition in every loop, which makes the computation time larger compared to **CODE 2**.

Is there a way to simplify **CODE 2** so that it has similar number of lines as **CODE 1**?

The code I'm writting has a numerous number of lines in a `for` loop and there are only few lines that are dependent on some flags. Since this loop has to be done a billion times, I want to reduce down the computational cost as much as I can.

---

As @kingkupps commented that it seems like an XY problem, I would like to give the actual problem I'm doing.

I have analysis data files which have the format as below.

```
<node no.>, <x-coord.>, <y-coord.>, <z-coord.>, <v-x>, <v-y>, <v-z>, ...
1,-1.758000000E+01, 7.859070503E-01,-6.661221083E+00, 1.853448047E+01, 0.000000000E+00, 0.000000000E+00, ...
2,-1.758000000E+01, 6.714303868E-01,-6.517660165E+00, 1.736286209E+01, 0.000000000E+00, 0.000000000E+00, ...
3,-1.758000000E+01, 8.324907476E-01,-6.482755077E+00, 1.709871564E+01, 0.000000000E+00, 0.000000000E+00, ...
4,-1.758000000E+01, 6.145584633E-01,-6.692237928E+00, 1.872061756E+01, 0.000000000E+00, 0.000000000E+00, ...
...
```

Beyond the velocity data, there are temperature, pressure, heat flux, and heat transfer coefficient data.

The data files have the same node numbers and the coordinates. Thus, I don't want to read the node nubmers and the coordinates from the second analysis file.

So I wrote a function to read the data as below.

---

**CODE 3**

```py
def read_result_file(file_name: str, is_read_node=False):
    if is_read_node:
        x_arr = []
    else:
        x_arr = None
    v_arr, T_arr, press_arr, heat_flux_arr, HTC_arr = [], [], [], [], []

    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        if is_read_node:
            for line in f:
                line = line.split(',')
                x = list(map(float, line[1:4]))
                v = list(map(float, line[4:8]))
                T = float(line[8])
                press = float(line[9])
                heat_flux = float(line[10:14])
                HTC = float(line[14])
                x_arr.append(x)
                v_arr.append(v)
                T_arr.append(T)
                press_arr.append(press)
                heat_flux_arr.append(heat_flux)
                HTC_arr.append(HTC)
        else:
            for line in f:
                line = line.split(',')
                v = list(map(float, line[4:8]))
                T = float(line[8])
                press = float(line[9])
                heat_flux = float(line[10:14])
                HTC = float(line[14])
                v_arr.append(v)
                T_arr.append(T)
                press_arr.append(press)
                heat_flux_arr.append(heat_flux)
                HTC_arr.append(HTC)

    v_arr = np.array(v_arr)
    T_arr = np.array(T_arr)
    press_arr = np.array(press_arr)
    heat_flux_arr = np.array(heat_flux_arr)
    HTC_arr = np.array(HTC_arr)
    if is_read_node:
        x_arr = np.array(x_arr)

    return v_arr, T_arr, press_arr, heat_flux_arr, HTC_arr, x_arr
```

In the for loops in **CODE 3**, there is only one difference of reading nodal coordinates. So, I want to reduce the length of the number of lines of the code while not increasing the number of condition checks.

Comment: Why do you want to add `1` to `a`? Why can't your `a_list` just be `a_list = [i+1 for i in range(n_iter)]` and `a` just be `a=n_iter`? In that case your code could be 2 lines: `a = n_iter` and `if flag: a_list = [i+1 for i in range(n_iter)]`.

Comment: I think the append thing was just an example to how his loop was supposed to work depending on the flag value

Comment: This seems like [an xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) as is. Can you elaborate more on your actual use case? If this is really the exact problem you are trying to solve, then I'd recommend doing what @ramzeek suggested.

Comment: hi @pdhwi93, the code could use a working example with actual data, several people have proposed an answer but it not clear if this is what you want, this seems like a  xy problem.

Comment: what is your format file in type (csv, txt, netcdf...etc)? it seems weird to get all strings, you could use pandas or numpy to load the file in to integers or floats, this would be much faster to use. This could be done in a single line of code.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looping through the items in the list every time no matter the value of the flag, you can shorten it to the following using list comprehensions but I don't know how it will affect memory usage a with large number of items:

```
a = 0
a_list = []
n_iter = 10
flag = False

result = [x+1 for x in range(n_iter)]
a += len(result)

if flag:
    a_list.extend(result)

print(a_list)
print(a)
```

If flag is False it prints:

```
[]
10
```

If flag is True it prints:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
10
```

Comment: Note the first value of `a_list` should be `1`, not `0`

Comment: @ramzeek I guess I missed that, thanks, Ill fix it

Answer (score 0):

in the CODE2, the flag is only being checked once and then rest of the for loop is being carried out. I think this is at least the number of lines that will be required, else where are you going to check the flag.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).